# How to Manage Moviepy Video Inside my PyGame Display? (x, y and sizing)

Tags: python, pygame, moviepy

How can I manage a moviepy video?
I have a 800x600 screen but and I want the moviepy video smaller than that, but my video always takes the display and goes full size (the moviepy size, ignoring my screen).

```py
pygame.init()

screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 800

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

clip = VideoFileClip('vds/anime.mp4').resize((400, 260))

def videoplayer():
    while True:
        clip.preview()#.draw(SCREEN,(100,200))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                clip.close()
                main_game()
```

I've stumbling in another problem, too: the "clip.close" command does not close the video but instead goes to main_game.